# rebase commits after master commits merged

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase

I have a master branch with all updated commits. The scenario happened is like this:

- create and checkout branch_a from the master
- I added a few commits in branch_a and a few commits in master individually
- Then I merged the master branch in branch_a
- Now add 2 more commits in branch_a

After then while creating a Pull Request for branch_a with comparison with the master I got something like this:

*In the picture assume branch 'referral_usage_condition_change' : 'branch_a'

[image]
Now I want to rebase all my commits of branch_a and making a single commit (As we have the restriction of adding a single commit for a PR in the master!)
How can I do this?

Comment: make interactive rebase to the first commit `git rebase -i 65763b8`

Comment: In this case, I rebased branch_a with master and I got all my commits on the top of master's commits. Then I squashed my all commits into one commit.